# Disconnecting app in quickbooks v3 api

Tags: java, quickbooks, disconnect

I am working on quickbooks v3 api integration. I have done all integrations but got stuck in Quickbooks Disconnect from app.

I am using the following snippet of code for disconnecting from quickbooks

```
final IAPlatformClient pClient = new IAPlatformClient();
pClient.disconnect(consumerkey, consumersecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
```

This code is throwing the following error

**Error Code: null,Error Message: Failed to disconnect: null null
    at com.intuit.ia.connection.PlatformHttpClient.disconnect(PlatformHttpClient.java:81)
    at com.intuit.ia.connection.IAPlatformClient.disconnect(IAPlatformClient.java:40)
    at com.intuit.ia.connection.IAPlatformClient$disconnect.call(Unknown Source)**

Not sure if i am missing any dependency for disconnect api as all other integrations(sign-in/blue-dot menu/connect to QB) are working fine with the v3 API.

I had done it using v2 quickbooks API and everything was working but getting this in v3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Quickbooks disconnect API at https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0060_auth_auth/0015_disconnect_api descripbed the URL requires a GEt request. So instead of going through the v3 API i also tried to make a GET request to the api url as follows

https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Disconnect?oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=secret&oauth_consumer_key=key&oauth_consumer_secret=secret

Now i get error code 50 "Missing appToken" error

Does the disconnect API work with GET request? Which parameter am i missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Link for Sample code for Quickbooks V3 API.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/tree/master/QuickbooksV3API

Comment: Your Quickbooks disconnect API link is broken.

Comment: Quickbooks recently updated their resources. Last i used was a long time back and above links were active. You can use this [link](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/tree/master/QuickbooksV3API) for sample code.

Comment: Rather than including the comment, can you edit your question to include the working link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add the latest(1.0.2) qbapihelper jar in your classpath and try the call.

Jar name - `ipp-java-qbapihelper-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Disconnect API doesn't have any issue. It worked fine. You can try this call using any standard RESTClient like fiddler. PFB details.

GET URI - https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Disconnect

Request Header -

```
content-type: application/xml
Host: appcenter.intuit.com
```

Response -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PlatformResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <ErrorMessage />
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
  <ServerTime>2013-12-24T10:09:48.7601Z</ServerTime>
</PlatformResponse>
```

The above response suggests a successful API call.
Ref - 
Edit - Updating the latest doc ref -
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0020_authentication_and_authorization/oauth_management_api#Disconnect

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. The jar ipp-java-qbapihelper.jar had the property for disconnect url missing in ia.properties file. Thats why the error was occurring. I included the property and recompiled the jar and now its working. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.. in the sample project.. user defined ia.properties file has that entry. that's why it works fine there.. In the next release, this issue will be fixed in the helper jar. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, It's works after adding new line disconnect on ia.properties file. But I am wondering, how it is working for reconnect? my api is working file in case of reconnect, Do you have any idea @ManasMukherjee ??

Comment: May be that endpoint is hard coded some where else. I'm not sure now. You can use jd-gui de-compiler to see if that is the case. Otherwise, on Monday I'll try to check and confirm. thanks

Comment: Your referenced link is broken.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for pointing this. There were many changes in the docs site. It was still referring to the old one. I've updated the link. Thanks