# How can I reconnect to the QBO API after token expiration using the java SDK

Tags: java, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to write an application which will connect to the Quickbooks Online API via a java spring engine, pull some data down and transform it, and email it somewhere.

I have all of this working, but my issue now is the 180 day expiration of my tokens for QBO.  I'd like to reconnect.  (I am using version 1.2.0 of the ipp-java-qbapihelper and 2.0.3 of ipp-v3-java-devkit).

I found this answer: [Disconnecting app in quickbooks v3 api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586739/disconnecting-app-in-quickbooks-v3-api) which talks about disconnecting (and telling you to edit your ia.properties file to include the disconnect url, which I did, adding `disconnect_url=https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Disconnect` ).

Since one version of this application is currently in production, I created another app and connected it to QBO via the steps here: http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1396  I have verified that the new app can connect to QBO by having it retrieve a customer.

Now I'm just trying to reconnect.  My general idea is to:

- try to reconnect
- if it fails, connect normally, since I am within the 180 days
- if it succeeds, use the new access tokens (and store them off so that subsequent calls can use them).

However, I can't reconnect or disconnect.  If I write code like:

```
IAPlatformClient client = new IAPlatformClient();
client.disconnect(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
```

I get this error message:

```
Error Code: 100,Error Message: Error Revoking Access for authId=xxx, realmId=, appToken=xxxx
```

It is interesting to me that the realmId is blank.  I don't see any way to set the realmid on IAPlatformClient or examples of how to use this class.  And the appToken is different than the apptoken I use to generate the context.

If I try to reconnect:

```
IAPlatformClient client = new IAPlatformClient();
client.reConnect(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
```

I get this error message:

```
Caused by: Error Code: null,Error Message: Failed to disconnect: java.lang.NullPointerException null
```

Is this because I'm using an app that is in development mode?  This is just an internal app moving data around our company, so I'm not sure whether I need to move it to production status.

Am I not supposed to use IAPlatformClient (if so, what should I use)?

Here's a url: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/ that lets you connect an app with less duration, but playing with that didn't seem to help--I couldn't find the access token and access token secret.

I've looked online (couldn't find much more than the SO question I mention above) and the IPP liveconnect forums.  I also looked at the sample QB java code: https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/ but that is geared toward a webapp, so I didn't find it all that useful.  I also read the disconnect documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect and I am unfortunately not getting any of the documented error messages.

The liveconnect forum had this post: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/800930-reconnect-c-or-net-example but it wasn't too helpful.  I also looked at this example from PHP https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/806889-how-should-i-call-reconnect-api-using-php which looks quite nice but doesn't translate to java.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this post(Re - Disconnect).

[Disconnecting app in quickbooks v3 api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586739/disconnecting-app-in-quickbooks-v3-api)

have you tried 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect' as mentioned in

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect

I'm not sure about the behavior of the Disconnect API(as I've not used it yet). 
After disconnection(or without), to get a new set of accessToken and AccessSecret you can go through stand C2QB(3-legged OAuth flow).

Either using sampleQBOV3App or using OAuthPlayground.
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

**UPDATE** - Adding working code without using java devkit.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.intuit.ipp.data.Account;
import com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException;
import com.intuit.ipp.net.MethodType;
import com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService;

public class POCWithoutDevkitTest {

    private DataService service;
    private OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer;
    private static String realmID = null;
    public static final String TEMPLATE_CONTENT_BOUNDARY = "\r\n\r\n--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\" %s\r\n%s\r\n";

    public POCWithoutDevkitTest() {
        realmID = "122294642099";
        String consumerKey = "AAAAA";
        String consumerSecret = "BBBBB";
        String accessToken = "CCCCC";
        String accessTokenSecret = "DDDDD";

        setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    }

    public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret) {
            this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
            oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
    }

    public void authorize(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) throws FMSException {
        try {
            oAuthConsumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        }
    }

    public void executeGetRequest(String customURIString){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");

        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = new URI(customURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String methodtype = "GET";

        if (methodtype.equals(MethodType.GET.toString())) {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
        }

        httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
        httpRequest.addHeader("Accept","application/xml");

        try {
            authorize(httpRequest);
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
            System.out.println("Connection status : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());

            InputStream inputStraem = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStraem, writer, "UTF-8");
            String output = writer.toString();

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        POCWithoutDevkitTest withoutDevkitClient = new POCWithoutDevkitTest();
        withoutDevkitClient.executeGetRequest("https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect");
    }

    private void testCall() {
        try {
            this.service.findAll(new Account());
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Manas, I did read the disconnecting post you reference.  It didn't help me--I tried both disconnect_url=https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Disconnect and disconnect_url=https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/disconnect .  I'm trying to use the reconnect API so I don't have to go through the 3 legged OAuth flow--from my reading I should be able to get new access tokens via the reconnect API.